# Publishing to Sharepoint from Eclipse

Tags: sharepoint, eclipse-plugin, tibco

I cant find any eclipse plugins to publish to Sharepoint. I wish to write a plugin for TIBCO Business Modeler (based on Eclipse) which publishes exported HTMLs to Sharepoint.

I cant also find the right API for Sharepoint to do this. Does Sharepoint have a REST API to enable publishing? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint folders can be mounted in Windows network folders using WebDAV and uploading files is like writing to the local file system.

Comment: This answer help to set up for me a way to sync HTML files developed in Eclipse with SharePoint Online. On our SharePoint Online (Office 365), we are storing HTML file that is linked to a content editor to execute jQuery/JavaScript on a List forms.